# Create folders/files with rwx permission on "others"

Tags: linux, permissions

We have a software that, during its execution, creates a folder with a bunch of files in it. Their permissions look something like

> drwxrwsr-x for folders
>
> -rw-rw-r-- for files

What we would like to achieve is having "rwx" permission on *others*, something like

> drwxrwsrwx for folders
>
> -rw-rw-rwx for files

And all of this should happen without calling *chmod* inside our software.
We were wondering if exists a particular combination of permissions to apply to that aforementioned software, in order to produce such results, or we have to fallback to chmod'ing every single file/folder generated right in the sourcecode.
Thanks :)

Comment: `mkdir -m 777 new_folder`? `umask 0` before creating folders and `umask 110` before creating files (although why you want the execute bit set on all files is a big question...)? What is wrong with `chmod`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether its gonna help you or not. But using `POSIX access Control` You can do achieve file permission without `chmod`. For that you will need to create acl.list and change permission to different users, Groups and Others as well. You can follow this link for more http://users.suse.com/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online

Comment: Thanks, we'll have a look and let you know.